# If not exist in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am passing datatable as input parameter to a stored procedure. I have created custom type for it.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_AddEmployee]
      @tblEmp EmpType READONLY,
      @Code int
AS
BEGIN    
      INSERT INTO Employee ([Name], [Lname], [Code])
         SELECT 
             [Name], [Lname], @Code 
         FROM @tblEmp
```

Here I fetching record from datatable and inserting into Employee table.
Datatable contain Name,Lname and mobileno.
I want to check combination of Name,Lname and mobileno.If combination of it present in Employee  table,pls don't insert record([Name], [Lname], @Code ) in Employee.Else Insert

Comment: tried Exists function?

Comment: Use a unique index on the 3 fields? You'd need to handle the error when the record already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Correlated SubQuery` with `NOT EXISTS` to find the existence of a record

```
INSERT INTO Employee
            ([Name],[Lname],[Code])
SELECT [Name],[Lname],@Code
FROM   @tblEmp A
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Employee B
                   WHERE  B.[Name] = A.[Name]
                          AND B.[Lname] = A.[Lname]
                          AND B.[mobno] = A.[mobno])
```

Comment: It is working properly.Can u pls tell me why u use 1 here.I did not understand this block.WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Employee B
                   WHERE  B.[Name] = A.[Name]
                          AND B.[Lname] = A.[Lname]
                          AND B.[mobno] = A.[mobno])

Comment: @JuiTest - It is just to find the existence of a row you can even place any `column names` there. Learn how exists work then you will undersatnd

Comment: Thanks for ur help.Now I got.Suppose datatable(have 3 column) contain 3 row.Name,LName and MobileNo.Here are the rows of datatable.I forgot to tell that mobileno is from different table.Mobile no is from contactdetail not from Employee.dataTable rows are 'Rani','Patil'987xxxxx'
'Shipra','kale',923xxxxx'
'Mohini','Hirve',8789xxxxx
So first time it will check

Comment: @JuiTest - If you have Question then ask it as a another question

Comment: SELECT 1
                   FROM   Employee B inner join contactdetail c on c.id = e.cid
                   WHERE  B.[Name] = 'Rani'
                          AND B.[Lname] = 'Patil'
                          AND c.[mobno] = '987XXX') If record not found,insert and second time SELECT 1
                   FROM   Employee B inner join contactdetail c on c.id = e.cid
                   WHERE  B.[Name] = 'Shipra'
                          AND B.[Lname] = 'kale'
                          AND c.[mobno] = '923xxxxx') Like his.It will run for 3 time because there are 3 rows.It will go through all rows

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_AddEmployee]
      @tblEmp EmpType READONLY,
      @Code int
AS
BEGIN    

INSERT INTO Employee ([Name], [Lname], [Code])
         SELECT 
             [Name], [Lname], @Code 
         FROM @tblEmp T
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
             [Name], [Lname], @Code 
         FROM Employee E where T.[Name]=E.[Name], T.[Lname]=E.[Lname] )

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO Employee
            ([Name],
             [Lname],
             [Code])
SELECT [Name],
       [Lname],
       @Code
FROM   @tblEmp t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Employee t2
                   WHERE  t1.[Name] = t2.[Name]
                          AND t1.[Lname] = t2.[Lname]
                          AND t1.[mobileno] = t1.[mobileno])
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not good in SQL but this way will work I guess

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_AddEmployee]
      @tblEmp EmpType READONLY,
      @Code int
AS
BEGIN    
DECLARE
  @EMPID INTEGER

     SELECT @EMPID = ISNULL(EMPID, 0) FROM EMPLOYEE 
     WHERE NAME = @NAME AND LNAME = @LNAME AND MOBILE =@Mobile
  IF EMPID = 0 THEN
     INSERT INTO Employee ([Name], [Lname], [Code])
         SELECT 
             [Name], [Lname], @Code 
         FROM @tblEmp
  END
END
```